# How do the D flip-flops in SAR logic work?

Tags: flipflop

D flip-flops with set and reset can only work when set = 1 = reset, and the Q value depends on D and clock, but in the SAR logic circuit shown below, we find set and reset aren't equal to 1 at the same time:

[image]

So, I am curious about how the D flip-flop works in SAR logic to let the SAR logic output become like:

D9=1, D8=0, ... D0=0

D9=0, D8=1, D7=0, ... D0=0

D9=0, D8=0, D7=1, D6=0, ... D0=0

and become D9=0, D8=0, D7=0, D6=0, ... D1=0, D0=1 in the end.

Comment: What is “SAR logic”?

Comment: Successive Approximation Register. Used in some kind of ADC. Comp is the output of a comparator between Vin and reconstructed voltage from a DAC with the SAR outputs..

Comment: It is the same ... that founding a number ( 0..1023) in a mimimum guess choices.

Answer (score 2):

The content of the upper "register" is a "moving 1", because the input of the register is a "0" ...
The first FF is set, the others are reset.
So the register shift shows successively: 10000, 01000, 00100, 00010, 00001 ...

Here is a simulation of the behavior of a 4 bits ADC, SAR type.
Note also that there is a "little" error when testing the original picture ...
The "rst" pulse is also the "start" convert.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The top group of Dffs generate a wavefront thusly

000000 <- upon the initial  reset
100000 <- upon first clk rising edge
110000 <- upon second clk rising edge
111000 <- upon third
111100
111110
111111

and the bottom group implement the testing/latching behavior of binary search.
The comparator logic-level determines whether the bit just set high, as the wave moves along to the right, will remain high after the wave moves one bit to the right.

The feedback from bit 7 "Q" to bit 8 "CLK" [ the triangle input ] is the digital signal performing the sample-the-comparator-output, and make that binary-search activity for that bit (which is controlling a DAC).

Have you drawn a timing diagram? Start with "reset", and "clock". and some random "Comp" NRZ pattern. And the Q outputs of all the FFs.

Comment: I set the signal of reset is 1. In first clk,D is on ground,so D=0.Q=1,for set=1 in First(Left) D-flip flop,then though second D-flipflop's input is 1, Q=0,for reset signal=1,so after 10 clk,it become 1000000000.But upon second clk rising edge ,the set in first d flip flop is still 1 ,and the other reset are still 1,so,shouldn't they  always 1000000000,why can they become 1100000000?

Comment: Reset can only occur at the start, then reset must end. Then the clocking starts.

Comment: you mean Reset=10000001?

Comment: excuse me,shouldn't the top group of Dffs be Straight ring counter,not Twisted Johnson  Counter ?

Comment: Could you please explain how the initial reset is done and why there are missing connections on some of the FF's?